# Adding UnderlayButton to Partial Swipe , and on further swiping the partial swipe to full swipe it will delete the item from Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I'm trying to Implement Partial Swipe and full swipe both on Recycler View Item. I've successfully Implemented the Partial swipe with UnderlayButton , Now I want to implement a feature in which If the user tries to swipe after the partial swipe, Item gets full swiped and is Deleted from RecyclerView.